# How can I add/replace to line in Stringbuilder?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I use the `Stringbuilder` to create a string like this: LS2234-32342-2342-06455. My issues is replace a string in line 19 "0" with an other string.

```
var key = new StringBuilder { Capacity = 24 };

key.Append("L");
......
```

How can I replace the line 19 with a other string? Array?

Comment: Do you mean character 19 rather than line 19?

Comment: Replace with what - another string or another character?

Comment: No i mean like this array[19] = "E";

Comment: The `StringBuilder` indexer requires a `char`.

Comment: Do you try google it before?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you might want this;

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("LS2234-32342-2342-06455");
sb.Remove(18, 1);
sb.Insert(18, 'E');
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Output will be;

```
LS2234-32342-2342-E6455
                  ^
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/Fryrhp)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

To replace the input at the 19th character you will need to access the 18th index.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("LS2234-32342-2342-06455");

sb[18] = '0';
```

See: [`StringBuilder.Chars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.chars.aspx)

Comment: is that feasible? I thought this only works with array :/

Comment: The `StringBuilder` has an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.chars.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Insert` you can solve this.

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("LS2234-32342-2342-06455");
            sb.Remove(18,1);
            // Insert a string to 19th position
            sb.Insert(18, "test");
```